# How many OWLs are needed to be able to continue your education?

Tags: harry-potter

Is there any hard requirement on the number of OWLs that you should pass a that you are allowed to continue to 6th year?  We know that Fred and George had three each and they were allowed to do so.

Any further information on the subject?

Comment: AFAIK, it depends which NEWT classes you want to take, and then you need to get the necessary grades. I always thought Fred and George were just taking a slimmed-down timetable in their final year.

Comment: Your OWLs seem to matter when it comes to your choice of subject. If you can find at least one professor willing to teach you, there doesn't seem to be a barrier to staying on. And since several professors have very low standards (one is dead, another is an alcoholic), getting very low owl scores doesn't seem to be a big problem.

Comment: one is dead, 3 more are alcoholic... fixed that for you.

Comment: Still there are passing and non-passing scores. Will you be able to enroll History of Magic with 'poor' on the OWL exam?

Comment: @vap78 - wasn't able to find anything in canon yet. But I recon that Binns wouldn't care one whit. Nor Ms. Sherry.

Comment: @DVK Three alcoholics? Hagrid? And… Slughorn? Dumbledore(’s original actor)?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Nope, not Dumbledore: Ms. Sherry, aka Trelawney, but don't worry she didn't see that one coming either ;) On the other hand she didn't start drinking that heavily until Umbridge ...

Comment: @BMWurm No, I meant which are the other two, apart from her, that make it three. Dumbledore was tongue-in-cheek: he doesn't drink in-universe (that we know of), but Richard Harris sure did.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I understood that :D   I only mentioned Trelawney and Dumbledore, since the other two are present and pretty obvious. Well, to be fair, only Trelawney is obvious, Hagrid is certainly drunk often enough to call him an alcoholic (depending on definition, of course: some doctors define someone regularlarly drinking alcohol as being alcoholic, so Hagrid definately counts). Same goes for Slughorn, who is more of a recreational drinker, but certainly regularly, hence, the definition applies (despite it making a whole lot of people alcoholics by definition, who aren't addicted, IMO)

Answer (score 4):

This isn't canon, but considering that the Hogwarts education is based around UK education, I'll answer using that as a reference.

In the UK, compulsory education finishes when secondary school ends at 16. This coincides with the OWLs, therefore I would assume that these are the equivalent of UK GCSEs.

Sixth form college is then attended for 2 years, in order to gain A Levels, which would then be directly replaced by the NEWTs in the HP universe.

In order to get into sixth form colleges, the number of GCSEs required varies depending on the establishment, but I think that most require 4 passing grades to enter.

If these are not gained, they can be supplemented by retaking certain subjects at GCSE in order to gain the minimum requirement alongside A level classes, so that the student does not have to postpone their further education.

As for the numbers of GCSEs compared to OWLs, I think that the number of GCSEs that most students take is around 9, with some of the better students attempting around 12-13. This appears to coincide with the number of courses taken by 16 year old wizards. Therefore I would assume that the number of passing grades required to progress with education is also similar.

The only issue is that there aren't exactly a great number of wizarding centers of further education outside of Hogwarts (as far as I'm aware). I've seen no evidence that drop-out wizards can go and do vocational courses, but I don't know the full extent of the HP Extended Universe.

So if Hogwarts is the only place that students can attend for further education, I would assume that the requirements for access would be fairly low, as there is no alternative for the less accomplished students.

Using this evidence, I would make the assumption that the minimum number of passing grade OWLs required to take the NEWTs is in fact 3.

It could quite possibly be 4, meaning that Fred and George may have been resitting one of their OWL exams in order to allow them to carry on studying at Hogwarts, however I can't see it being any fewer than 3 based on the parallels between UK education and HP education.

Comment: The number of GCSEs taken by most students coincides with the number of courses taken by muggle students? Wouldn't those be the same students? Was that supposed to say OWLs?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks, I missed that. I've updated.